# phpMyAdmin redirecting to different server

Tags: phpmyadmin, centos, http-status-code-404, redirect

I am not entirely sure what has happened or changed in the last few days. I have two environments for the same site, a staging and production. Both run on CentOS 6.5 and Apache 2.2.15. For some reason in the staging environment, the phpmyadmin page there either reports back a **404 not found error** after redirecting to the phpmyadmin page of my production site.

I have checked my `.htaccess` file in the public directory, `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`, and `/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf`to make sure no redirects are configured but have not found anything.

My `phpMyAdmin.conf` has the correct aliases configured as well. This is it's config:

```
Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
  AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

  <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     Require local
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Allow,Deny
     Allow from All
  </IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/>
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     Require local
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from IP.AD.DR.ESS
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

I tried restarting apache and MySQL but still have no resolution. I also tried updating all of my yum packages but to no avail.

Nothing is being reported in my error logs either so I am a bit stumped as to where this redirect is coming from. Is there somewhere else I am not checking? As far as I know, no file permissions have been changed and it is only myself and another developer that works inside this server. Some other background info, we also have a disk cache enabled and gzip compression. The site is also password protected in order to gain access.

Any guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: Is there a proxy server between you and the Apache server? Also, do you see your request in access_log?

Comment: There's no proxy server and I'm not able to see it in my access_log. I even rolled back the server but for some reason it's still redirecting to the production site's page.